# Throwing two exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to throw exceptions for when the user enters anything else besides a 0 or a 1 because I am making a Binary to Decimal Converter. How am I able to throw the same message for each error the user makes? Here is my code and it is telling me the second **throw NumberFormatException** cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
if(!string.contains("0")){
        throw new NumberFormatException("The number must be 0 or 1.");
        if(!string.contains("1")){
            throw NumberFormatException;
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a boolean and (`&&`). Something like

```
if(!string.contains("0") && !string.contains("1")){
    throw new NumberFormatException("The number must be 0 or 1.");
}
```

Additionally, you can't throw an exception class like an `Exception` instance.

```
throw NumberFormatException;
```

is missing `new` and `()`. Like,

```
throw new NumberFormatException();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense. Wouldn't the comparison be a (||) though because it needs to be a 1 OR 0? Or is (&&) correct?

Comment: @Codet And is correct, because you want to throw the exception if the `string` doesn't contain `1` **and** it doesn't contain `0`

Comment: Ahhhhh. Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: @Codet See also [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws); `!(a || b)` is the same proposition as `(!a && !b)`.

Comment: Dang. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Codet remember to **accept** the answer that is helped. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)